# spark closures-Variable life cycle and binding

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am struggling to understand variable lifecycle in spark closures and how spark serialize and distribute code to executor.

I have listed 3 different scenerions to supply an object to map transformation. What I understood from spark wiki [Spark Closure](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-a-nameclosureslinka) is that only scenerio 3 will work and rest will throw an exception when I run job in distributed mode`(master=yarn)`. Though scenerio 1 is not using Broadcast variable but still produces the same results as scenerio 2.
What I want to understand is how scenerio 1 is different than 2?

**Test Bean class**

```
public class TestBean  implements Serializable {
    String val;
    public TestBean(String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
    public String message(Integer msg){
        return String.format("%s==>%d",val,msg);
    }
}
```

**Map function to append message**

```
public class Fn implements Function<Integer,String> {
    TestBean obj;
    public Fn(TestBean obj ){
        this.obj=obj;
    }
    @Override
    public String call(Integer param) throws Exception {
        return "Fn:"+obj.message(param);
    }
}
```

**Create RDD with 5 numbers:**

```
    TestBean bean = new TestBean("Hello");
    JavaRDD<Integer> rdd = context.parallelize(IntStream.range(0, 5).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

**Possible ways to pass object reference to map transformation:**

1. ***SUpply TestBean object reference using function-***

   ```
   rdd.map(new Fn(bean)).collect();
   ```
2. ***Supply testBean using Broadcast variable:***

   ```
     Broadcast<TestBean> beanBroadCast = context.broadcast(bean);
     rdd.map(obj -> beanBroadCast.getValue().message(obj)).collect();
   ```
3. ***Refer directly using lambda expression:***

   ```
   rdd.map(obj -> bean.message(obj)).collect();
   ```